# funcionamiento del boton

Tags: javascript, html, function

hola tengo este boton dentro de un foreach que itera una tabla

```
  <tr>
  <td><option id="cve" value="<?php echo "$c"; ?>"><?php echo 
   "$c"; ?></option></td>
             <td><option id="tur" value="<?php echo "$t"; ?>"><?php 
     echo 
   "$t"; ?></option></td> 
    <td><button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btn_seleccionar" 
    name="btn_seleccionar">Seleccionar</button></td>
  </tr>
```

y tengo esta function al oprimir el boton

```
  $("#btn_seleccionar").click(function () {

    var datos = {
        cve_i: $("#cve").val(),
        turn: $("#tur").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "estilos.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: datos,

        success: function (result) {
            $("#resultado1").html(result);
        }
    })
})
```

pero el boton solo toma el valor del primer renglon de la tabla , intento oprimir el siguiente boton del segundo o tercer, etc renglon y no hace nada ,me pordrian ayudar.

Comment: lo que pasa es que toma el id del primer elemento que halle en este caso todos tienene el mismo ID, debes crear id dinamicos

Comment: disculpa y como seria eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saludos podrias hacer algo asi:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($resultado as $item) {
    $i++;
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".;
   echo "</tr> <option id='cve_".$i."' value='".$item[valor]."'>";
   echo "<button onclick='consultar(".$i.");'>Seleccionar</button>"
}
```

ahora en tu javascript recibe el numero de id asignado a cada uno de los elementos:

```
function consultar(numero_id){
  alert(numero_id);
  var datos = {
        cve_i: $("#cve_"+numero_id).val(),
        ....
 };
   $.ajax({
        url: "estilos.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: datos,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#resultado1").html(result);
        }
    })


}//end function consultar
```

si te fijas dentro de button le envio el numero de id asignado por php , e invoco a un funcion consultar y  listo, espero te sirva....suerte..!!

Comment: gracias  diego avila me sirvió de mucho solo en  el onclick='consultar(" "); dentro de el coloque el resultado en php de las variables y así funciono perfectamente , gracias!